# How to add symbol in regular expression by condition?

Tags: regex

I need to add `0` if a founded number is less than `10` in the regular expression:

My expressions:

- searching string:
  `"createdAt":\s+\[\s+([0-9]+),\s+([0-9]+),\s+([0-9]+),\s+([0-9]+),\s+([0-9]+),\s+([0-9]+)\s+]`
- replacing:
  `"createdAt": "($1)-($2)-($3)T($4):($5):($6)"`
- Result:

Input data:

```json
"createdAt": [
            2022,
            4,
            15,
            13,
            43,
            7
          ]
```

Expected output data:

```json
"createdAt":"2022-04-15T13:43:07"
```

Actual output data (4 except 04 and 7 except 07):

```json
"createdAt":"2022-4-15T13:43:7"
```

--

So, how to add conditions in this case?

Comment: Changing JSON using regex is almost always a bad idea. You're better off using tools that are designed for the job.

Comment: Regular expressions don't add things by themselves. You need a programming language of some sorts. What are you using?

Comment: @trincot not quite so, there is I found a similar tutorial, but can't implement it in the my solution yet: https://www.regular-expressions.info/replaceconditional.html

Comment: Sure there is a syntax for replacement, but it is employed by programming languages. Which are you using?

Comment: @Ivar I have a task and, unfortunately, can't say the same answer to the my customer

Comment: @trincot this expression will be used not by me

Comment: Then I think we should close this question. Parsing JSON via regular expression is bad practice.

Comment: @trincot I don't think so. In any case, this is a good an useful question and this issue has a solution.

Comment: Useful to who @ValentynHruzytskyi? We already have the occasional questions here on Stack Overflow asking how to fix their malformed JSON, to which the answer is, that it is near impossible. Even if they don't want to believe it, mixing regex and JSON is a terrible idea as it is very easy to make mistakes and be left with unrecoverable data. I'm also not sure why you can't tell your customer that. They are asking you because you are the professional. Nobody is helped by providing them terrible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with manipulating the array:

```js
const json = {
  "createdAt": [
    2022,
    4,
    15,
    13,
    43,
    7
  ]
}

const formattedJson = json.createdAt.map((n) => n.toString().padStart(2, 0))

console.log(formattedJson);
```

Or using regex on the date string:

```js
const date = "2022-4-15T13:43:7"
const formattedDate = date.replace(/\b(\d)\b/g, '0$1')

console.log(formattedDate);
```

Breakdown of `/\b(\d)\b/g`

- `\b` - Word boundary. In this case we're wrapping a boundary around any single digit.
- `\d` - Any digit 0-9
- `()` - Capturing group. This allows us to reference anything between the parentheses at a later point.

This is the replacement `'0$1'`. The `$1` is how we reference the capturing group. If we had multiple capturing groups, we'd reference the second one with `$2`, the third with `$3`, etc..

In this case we're just saying - look for any single digit and replace it with a `0` and the digit itself.

Comment: Note that the Asker had not mentioned they are working with JavaScript (at the time of writing this).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I increased your answer, by I need the solution exactly in the regular expression, not via code

Comment: @trincot For some reason I thought it was tagged Javascript but you're right, there's no mention of anything other than regex.

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi I'm confused as to what that means exactly.

Comment: You can found some example here https://www.regular-expressions.info/replaceconditional.html

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi, the problem is that this is documentation on regular expressions, but doesn't show how you **trigger** a replacement to happen -- this is driven by something external to this syntax. Which programming environment are you using regular expressions with?

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi That didn't clear things up for me. Regular expressions require a programming language. The link you posted mentions a **capturing group**. Thats part of what's going on with this `/\b(\d)\b/g, '0$1'`. I'll add some explanation to the answer to try and clarify